# Can simple Java synchronized block throws Exception?

Tags: java, synchronized

Let's say that I have this block of code inside a method:

```
...
synchronized (this) {
    this.var = value;
}
...
```

Could there be any scenario that makes that `synchronized` block throws an exception (assuming `this`, `var`, and `value` having non `null` values)?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, lots, but we don't know what types they are, so it's hard to be exact.

Comment: @SteveSmith what exceptions are you thinking of?

Comment: @Andy Turner Maybe a casting exception?(off the top of my head).  Although would they be caught by the compiler?

Comment: @SteveSmith I suppose you could get that, if you were using raw types. I'll give you that one; can't think of any others, though.

Comment: @SteveSmith assuming that the codes are correct (0% chance of casting errors and null pointer exceptions), would there still be any chance for the `synchronized` to throw exception?

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: @sokokaleb, is this question purely theoretical? If not, then you could get a better answer by providing some additional context. For example: why do you think this block of code could've thrown exception?

Comment: @Vasiliy I'd say yes. I'm currently refactoring some legacy codes, and one part of them contain a `try`-`catch` surrounded `synchronized` block with really simple lines contained inside the block (no exception-throwing lines at all). Hence it sparks my curiosity whether it's safe to remove the `try`-`catch` block.

Comment: @sokokaleb, I've never seen a `try-catch` around `synchronized`, and I can't think of even one single reason to have it that way. You can probably assume that either the guy who wrote this code was not brilliant, or that this `try-catch` contained additional code which was removed at some point. BTW, you could post that block of code and get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java Language Specification about the synchronized statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) :

> The executing thread locks the monitor associated with V. Then the Block is executed [...]

And the [Java virtual Machine Specification on Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.10), that explains how the mentioned monitors are to be used, only talks about exceptions being thrown from within the synchronized block. So the `synchronized` statement itself isn't permitted to throw an exceptions.

So there can't be any scenario in your case where an exception gets thrown.

Comment: reading a bit [further](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19-300-C-B): "If execution of the Block completes abruptly for any reason, then the monitor is unlocked and the synchronized statement completes abruptly for the same reason. "

Comment: Yes but `this.var = value;` can't complete abruptly unless there is a bug in the JVM and then all bets are off in terms of handling any resulting throwable.

Comment: I think stopping the Thread, despite deprecated, will cause this statement to complete abruptly with a ThreadDeath Error... the question is about the synchronized throwing an Exception, not about "handling" it, 
*sure, neither about it throwing an* **Error** but it still maybe a scenario that the OP needs to consider. *Not meant to contradict, but only complement your answer*